# Open Source Job Scheduler with REST API

Tags: rest, workflow, scheduler, job-scheduling

Are there any open source Job Scheduler with REST API for commercial use which will support features like:

- Tree like Job dependency
- Hold & Release
- Rerun failed steps
- Parallelism

Help would be appreciated :)

NOTE: we are looking for open source alternative for [TWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Tivoli_Workload_Scheduler),[Control-M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMC_Control-M),[AutoSys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JobScheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm) would seem to meet your requirements:

- Open Source see: [Open Source and Commercial Licenses](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=115&page=osource_scheduler_support_en.htm)
- Rest API see: [Web Service Integration](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=72&page=osource_scheduler_features_en.htm#web)
- Parallelism see: [Organisation of Jobs and Job Chains](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=72&page=osource_scheduler_features_en.htm#job_chains)

I think that these areas are also covered (I downloaded and trialled the application): See [here](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=72)

- Tree like Job dependency
- Hold & Release
- Rerun failed steps

I'm not affiliated with SOS GmbH

Comment: the job scheduler link is broken

Comment: The app is still there on https://www.sos-berlin.com/en

Answer (score 4):

ProActive Scheduler is an open source job scheduler.

- It is [part of OW2 organization](http://www.ow2.org/view/ActivitiesDashboard/ProActive)
- It is written in Java so it comes with a Java and a REST API
- It provides [workflows](http://doc.activeeon.com/ProActiveUserGuide.html#_jobs_workflows_and_tasks) that are set of tasks with dependencies and more (loop,replicate, branch), upon failures you can control if the task should be cancelled or restarted
- Parallelism and distribution is at the heart of it, with features like for instance

Commercial Support is provided by Activeeon, the company behind ProActive (full disclosure: I work for Activeeon).

Comment: The company web site is http://activeeon.com/  and the github repo is here https://github.com/ow2-proactive/scheduling

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in DKron

> Dkron is a system service that runs scheduled jobs at given intervals or times, just like the cron unix service but distributed in several machines in a cluster. If a machine fails (the leader), a follower will take over and keep running the scheduled jobs without human intervention. Dkron is Open Source and freely available.

http://dkron.io/

Answer (score -1):

While not open source, a more cost effective job scheduler solution with REST API and support for the features listed is ActiveBatch workload automation and job scheduling. I do work for the company (being up-front) but our customers love how they can easily extend their automated processes to connect to any application, any service, any server with our REST API adapter. You can get more information here: https://www.advsyscon.com/en-us/activebatch/rest-api-adapter