# a Method to Updating REST API data in periodic time?

Tags: javascript, rest, rss, scheduled-tasks

i dunno how to put it. Hope the title is right for my problem or scenario.

I want to build a REST API, with a data coming from many rssfeed web. Right now, i'm able to fetch the data using a script javascript and saving it in my database. To be able fetch that data, i have to open a page so the script will be able to run and reload every 1 minute. The Rest Api is still in localhost by the way.

> The Question is, what if i want to host it, should i have 1 PC to
>   always running 24 hours which only open a browser and access a REST
>   API address so the script will keep running and the data will always
>   be up to date?

Right now this the only method in my head, is there any method that i shouldn't have 1 pc to running 24hours a day seven days a week.

Comment: Are you planning to deploy your service on any server? Like Node.js or Apache or Tomcat? The best solution of your problem is to setup a scheduler that will be running on a predefined period, and fetch the data and store it in DB internally and you don't need to open a page to do that if you are not modifying the response returned from rssfeed.

Comment: yeah i have a plan to do that in the future, right now is still on the localhost. Can you give me a litle more example? i still don't get it,

Comment: You can go through this, [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393613/open-source-job-scheduler-with-rest-api) , [Tutorial](https://github.com/martijnboland/appoints-api-node), [Node-Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide). These are some of the example which you can use based on your requirements

Comment: thanks dude for your information,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution of your problem is to setup a **scheduler** that will be running on a predefined period, and fetch the data and store it in DB internally and you don't need to open a page to do that if you are not modifying the response returned from rssfeed.

You can go through this, [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393613/open-source-job-scheduler-with-rest-api) , [Tutorial](https://github.com/martijnboland/appoints-api-node), [Node-Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide). These are some of the example which you can use based on your requirements